# How to create a 4 div's with slope effect using css in the below mentioned format?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to create a banner structure using 4 divs and 4 images with slope effect using css. Exactly like the above mentioned format. Please support me.

Comment: would you show a attempt to us

Comment: check below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do that using `clip-path`. See snippet below:

```css
.parent {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.child{
  min-height:150px;
  width:25%;
  display:inline-block;
}
.child:nth-child(1) {
  width:30%;
  background: red;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left:-10%;
  width:30%;
  background: black;
 clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 80% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
.child:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left:-10%;
  width:40%;
  background: midnightblue;
}
.child:nth-child(4) {
  margin-left:-10%;
  width:30%;
  background: green;
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="child">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="child">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="child">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

You can find more documentation on clip path here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Answer (score 3):

Here is your code structure. Working properly on full screen preview.

```css
.container{
  overflow:hidden;
  height:15rem;
  display:flex;
}

.box{
  height:20rem;
  flex:1
}

.box_1{
  background:red;
  transform:rotate(15deg) scale(1.5)
}

.box_2{
  background:black;
  flex:1.5;
}

.box_3{
  background:midnightblue;
  transform:rotate(-15deg) scale(1.5)
}

.box_4{
  background:green;
  transform:rotate(15deg) scale(1.5)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box_1"></div>
  <div class="box box_2"></div>
  <div class="box box_3"></div>
  <div class="box box_4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: good idea! some may consider `clip-path: polygon()` but it has lower browser support

Answer (score 1):

There can also be the `background-gradient` option for plain background colors.

```css
header {
  background: red;
}

header div {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.5em 3%;
  margin:0 -1.5%;/* overlapp them or not , optionnal */
}

header div+div {
  background: linear-gradient(95deg, transparent 5%, black 5.5%)
}

header div:nth-child(3n) {
  background: linear-gradient(-95deg, rgb(7, 29, 101) 94%, transparent 94.5%);
}

header div:nth-child(4n) {
  background: linear-gradient(95deg, transparent 5%, rgb(10, 101, 7) 5.5%)
}


/* possible style for demo */

header {
  display: flex;/* flex/grid/table are fine*/
  width: 900px;/* whatever*/
  max-width: 100%;/* whatever*/
  min-width: 400px;/* whatever*/
  margin: 1em auto;/* whatever*/
  color: white;
  counter-reset: divs;/* demo*/
  overflow:hidden;
}

/* whatever*/
header div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align:justify;
}

header:first-of-type div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs);
  color: white;
  font-size: 5em;
  margin: auto;
}
body {margin:0;}
```

```html
<header>
  <div> </div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</header>

<header>
  <div>some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
  </div>
  <div>some text here some text here some texthere some text here some text here some text
  </div>
  <div>some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
  </div>
  <div>some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text 
  </div>
</header>
```

`transform:skew(x)` might also be an option if images are involved

```css
body {margin:0;}
div {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
}
nav {
  display:flex;
  height:15em;
  margin:0 -5vw
}
nav a {
  flex:1;
  border:solid;
  height:100%;
  transform:skew(-15deg);
  overflow:hidden;
  display:flex;
  text-decoration:none;
}
nav a + a {
  margin-left:3vh;
}
nav a img {
  width:140%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  /* optionnal */
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position:center center;
  transform:skew(15deg);
  margin:0 -20% 0 -20%;
  position:absolute;
}
nav a p {
  position:relative;
  margin:auto;
  max-width:15vw;
  text-align:center;
  color:#eff;
  font-family:cursive;
  border-radius:0.2em;
  background:rgba(100,130,0,0.75);
  font-size:2vw;
  padding:0.5em;
  transform:skew(15deg);
  box-shadow:0 0 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href=""><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/architecture">>
    <p>lorem ipsum linked</p>
  </a>
  <a href=""><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature">>
    <p>lorem ipsum linked</p>
  </a>
  <a href=""><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/people">>
    <p>My great</p>
  </a>
  <a href=""><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech">
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  </a>
</nav>
```